# Using LIKE(or any other method) to link records that they are similar or not similar only for some letters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that both have names of villages. They are not in English, and since the sources of records are different, they were filled differently. For instance, in Table A, a village's name is `'ABCDEFGHIJK'` and in Table B is `'ABCDEFGH-IJK'`. The difference in one or two letters, in addition the state and zone of the villages are included in both tables, so, the probability of similarity of two villages in the same zone is quite low. However, they are not matched 100%. What would you suggest to link those records.
[image]

In the above picture, I have a main table, which the data is correct, and I'm using it as the index file, and there are Table 2, which includes data of each village. BUT!!! The name of villages in table 2 is not filled correctly.
So, I needed to fill the data with correct data.
If your suggestion includes a SQL Query, that would be very appreciated.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Some sample data and an idea of the required output would help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How many rows are we talking, and do you need to do this regularly? Something like [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (which has several answers for SQL Server already on SO, from what I remember) might help, but it's expensive, so you don't want to do too many iterations with it... (`SOUNDEX` and `DIFFERENCE` might help, but I think they're designed specifically for English pronunciation...)

Comment: I included it in the question.

Comment: I'm not needing it regularly, but there are 8 files, like that.

Comment: Village name just contains/include alphabetic?

Comment: Some numbers are included, but not too many of them. They can be omitted

Comment: Try my code in answer below. Hope it helps

Comment: I think the only "built-in" solution that might handle something like this from Microsoft would be the ["fuzzy lookup" component in SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx), but that can be tough to get into if you've never used it before...

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you should remove special character in Village column in Table2.

Then, you compare two table based on Village column (and other if have)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURN VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(100)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'   -- or '%[^a-z1-9]%' if includes numberic
    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    RETURN @Temp
END


SELECT T1.*, T2.Population
FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY Table2 T2
WHERE T1.State = T2.State -- if have
   AND T1.Zone = T2.Zone  -- if have
   AND T1.Name = (SELECT dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(T2.Name))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nguyễn.

Comment: But, first off, it's not in English, and secondly, it's not all about non-alphabetic characters. Typos, different character usage in name of villages, and even omitting some letters, are parts of the problem.

Comment: Oh, as you said, if village in table2 is `ABC`, it will match all?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for my bad Eng! I mean, if first row in Table2 is: Tehran - A - ABC - 6, it will correct with 1st and 2nd row from table1?

Comment: You can think of as this: I am the main office, and I asked from all states to send me the population of their villages. They sent me table 2, that had no unique ID, and they used the names that are common in those areas, and of course some typos. They delivered data in excel files. However, to use the collected data in a report. I have all names of villages in all country in Table 1, and I need to put the collected data of Table 2 in Table 1, but I had no unique ID, but the names of villages which do not match each other, so I should find a way to link each records.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a noise table that will have all those noisy characters (like *,/,etc...).

Table schema will be somewhat like

```
DECLARE @tblNoise(Noise VARCHAR(4),ReplaceValues VARCHAR(4))
```

Then clean the Village values from Table 2 by using the noise table.

Once that is done, the you can perform the match between two tables.

For cleaning the noises, you can take the help of a UDF.

Also, you can use **SSIS** for your operation(if you have such an option at your disposal)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, many of them are misspelling and typos, not only wild characters.

Comment: @Yousef, then how about using SOUNDEX  or Levenshtein distance function along with that.